# sp_getapplock transaction within transaction

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a very quick question in regards to sp_getapplock.
Is calling sp_getapplock with the same resource (lock id) from one stored procedure to another allowed?

For example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [uspTest1]
(
    ...
    ...
)
AS
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        ...
        ...
        EXEC @RC = sp_getapplock @Resource = "Test 123",
                                 @LockMode = 'Exclusive',
                                 @LockOwner = 'Transaction',
                                 @LockTimeout = 60000,
                                 @DbPrincipal = 'public';
        IF @RC NOT IN (0, 1) THROW 50000, 'Unable to obtain lock', 1;
        ...
        ...
        EXEC [uspTest2] ..., ..., ...
    COMMIT
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    THROW
END CATCH


-- Test 2
CREATE PROCEDURE [uspTest2]
(
    ...
    ...
)
AS
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
        EXEC @RC = sp_getapplock @Resource = "Test 123",
                                 @LockMode = 'Exclusive',
                                 @LockOwner = 'Transaction',
                                 @LockTimeout = 60000,
                                 @DbPrincipal = 'public';
        IF @RC NOT IN (0, 1) THROW 50000, 'Unable to obtain lock', 1;
        ...
        ...
        ...
    COMMIT
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    THROW
END CATCH
```

Since the @Resource (lock id) are the same, will it fail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would expect that the call to [`sp_getapplock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189823.aspx) from within `uspTest2` return 0, i.e. "The lock was successfully granted synchronously", because you are holding this lock already in this transaction.

I think you are still in the same transaction and it is OK to call `sp_getapplock` several times within the same transaction.

You should try and check.

You may have other problems with nested transactions, if you use them as you've shown, though. For example, if for any reason `ROLLBACK` is called from `uspTest2`, it will rollback all nested transactions, everything to the point when `BEGIN TRANSACTION` was called in `uspTest1`. Do you really want it?

Instead of using nested `BEGIN TRANSACTION` in `uspTest2` consider using [`SAVE TRANSACTION savepoint_name`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188378.aspx) and then `ROLLBACK savepoint_name`.

Comment: Thanks Vladimir! Yes, I intended if there are any problems, I would like to rollback all transaction.

Comment: Ad I stated in my answer though, Vladimir does not address that multiple locks require multiple releases. Always bear that in mind with this.

Comment: Hi Rachel, I am using @LockOwner = 'Transaction'. Do I need to manually release the lock? I thought COMMIT or ROLLBACK will take care of it?

Comment: @RachelAmbler, the docs page that you quoted says "Locks associated with the current transaction are released when the transaction commits or rolls back." You can release the lock explicitly using `sp_releaseapplock` if you need to release it before transaction finishes, but you don't have to. Yes, if you want to release it explicitly, you need to call `sp_releaseapplock` same number of times as you called `sp_getapplock`.

Comment: And if that's the way you design code then you're in for a world of hurt. Any good developer knows to always keep track of what they create and what they release. The moment you just assume that it should work because you thought you created them all inside a Transaction, is the moment you're up at 3:30AM on a Sunday morning trying to work out why your application is behaving badly only to find out a lock that was inside a transaction is now outside and has now not been released.

Comment: @RachelAmbler, I agree that in general it is a good habit to free resources that you've acquired. But, in this case `sp_getapplock` has owner 'Transaction'. If the source code of the stored procedure is drastically changed and this call suddenly becomes outside a transaction, it will fail without acquiring a lock. Wouldn't it? I treat it like creating `CSingleLock` or `CWaitCursor` object on stack in C++ where I rely on compiler to call destructor. In this case SQL Server takes care of releasing the lock.

Comment: @RachelAmbler, besides, depending on what you try to do with the help of `sp_getapplock` you may not have a choice. If you have a procedure that has a transaction and you want to guarantee that only one copy of this procedure runs at any time, you shouldn't release the lock yourself explicitly with `sp_releaseapplock`. When do you want to call `sp_releaseapplock`? Just before `COMMIT`? Transaction is not finished yet, but another instance of procedure may start - we don't want it. After `COMMIT`? Too late - lock has been already released automatically. It has to be done by the server itself.

Comment: And again I say if this is how you always code then you're in for a world of hurt. Everything you say is true. And everything is fine right up until someone screws up and doesn't define the app lock call correctly, doesn't release it properly and blammo. I know this to be true because I've lived through nightmares just like it and I'm the one who's been cursing the developer who never thought twice because they'd always done it the same way until 'this one bit of code'...

Comment: @RachelAmbler, I'm not talking about how I "always code", I'm talking only about `sp_getapplock` and `sp_releaseapplock` here. I would appreciate it if you could take the given source code from the question and add it to your answer with demonstration for future readers of the proper correct use of `sp_releaseapplock` in this case.

Comment: I use `sp_getapplock` with transactions frequently and never explicitly release them as long as I want the lock to last for the transaction life time. The argument that "a lock that was inside a transaction is now outside and has now not been released" doesn't apply because if the lock owner is transaction and you try and do that no lock is taken and you get a warning message. Relying on the transaction is much more reliable and less error prone than trying to do it manually (including possibility that execution is aborted)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can call it multiple times - however if you call it twice you MUST release it twice. If the second call is stronger than the first then the result will be a union of the two.

Source [BOL - sp_getapplock (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189823.aspx)

> If sp_getapplock is called multiple times for the same lock resource,
>   but the lock mode that is specified in any of the requests is not the
>   same as the existing mode, the effect on the resource is a union of
>   the two lock modes. In most cases, this means the lock mode is
>   promoted to the stronger of the lock modes, the existing mode, or the
>   newly requested mode. This stronger lock mode is held until the lock
>   is ultimately released even if lock release calls have occurred before
>   that time. For example, in the following sequence of calls, the
>   resource is held in Exclusive mode instead of in Shared mode.

Source [BOL - sp_releaseapplock (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178602.aspx)

> **Remarks**
>
> When an application calls sp_getapplock multiple times for the same
>   lock resource, sp_releaseapplock must be called the same number of
>   times to release the lock